# Como exibir duas tabelas diferente na mesma view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Utilizando o Laravel 5.6
Estou tentando exibir duas tabelas diferntes na mesma view, mas está dando erro

esse é meu controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\NossaCasa;
use App\NossacasaTitulo;

class NossaCasaController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $nossacasa = NossaCasa::all();
        return view('nossacasa.nossacasa', array('nossacasa' => $nossacasa)); 
        $nossacasatitulo = NossacasaTitulo::find(1);
        return view('nossacasa.nossacasa', array('nossacasa' => $nossacasatitulo));       
    }   

}
```

O erro está retornando na página é o seguinte

> "Undefined variable: nossacasatitulo (View:
>   /home/centroculturalvastimilla/www/admin/resources/views/nossacasa/nossacasa.blade.php)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa incluir no array em `view` todos os valores que você quer utilizar, veja;

```
return view('nossacasa.nossacassa', [
    'nossacasatitulo' => $nossacasatitulo,
    'nossacassa' => $nossacasa
])
```